# Cannot make any query to Solr

Tags: solr, solrj, solandra

I am trying to setup Solandra (Solr + Cassandra), and to use it using SolrJ library. I managed to setup everything and add some documents using SolrJ, but when I tried to make a query it failed. I tried to execute query through url but it failed also. 
I used:

```
http://localhost:8983/solandra/my_core/select?q=*:*&wt=xml
```

And in my app I used following code:

```
CommonsHttpSolrServer server = new CommonsHttpSolrServer(url);
server.setParser(new XMLResponseParser());
SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery();
query.setQuery("some"); 
query.setStart(0);
query.setRows(10); 
QueryResponse response = server.query(query);
```

This is stacktrace that I got:

> org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: java.lang.StackOverflowError at
>   org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchHandler.handleRequestBody(SearchHandler.java:281)
>   at
>   org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:129)
>   at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:1368) at
>   org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.execute(SolrDispatchFilter.java:356)
>   at
>   solandra.SolandraDispatchFilter.execute(SolandraDispatchFilter.java:171)
>   at
>   org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:252)
>   at
>   solandra.SolandraDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolandraDispatchFilter.java:137)
>   at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1212)
>   at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:399)
>   at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
>   at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:766)
>   at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
>   at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326) at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
>   at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:928)
>   at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:549) at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212) at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404) at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.bio.SocketConnector$Connection.run(SocketConnector.java:228)
>   at
>   org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
>   Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError at
>   java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method) at
>   java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:150) at
>   java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:121) at
>   java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:235) at
>   java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:254) at
>   org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.isStale(HttpConnection.java:506)
>   at
>   org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.closeIfStale(HttpConnection.java:431)
>   at
>   org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$HttpConnectionAdapter.closeIfStale(MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager.java:1313)
>   at
>   org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:382)
>   at
>   org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
>   at
>   org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
>   at
>   org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:323)
>   at
>   org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CommonsHttpSolrServer.request(CommonsHttpSolrServer.java:422)
>   at
>   org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CommonsHttpSolrServer.request(CommonsHttpSolrServer.java:244)
>   at
>   org.apache.solr.handler.component.HttpCommComponent$1.call(SearchHandler.java:421)
>   at
>   org.apache.solr.handler.component.HttpCommComponent$1.call(SearchHandler.java:393)
>   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
>   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166) at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
>   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
>   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166) at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

Could it be that I missed something in schema.xml? This is how it looks like:

```
<schema name="my_core" version="1.1">
 <types>
  <fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField"/>
  <fieldType name="text_general_rev" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.ReversedWildcardFilterFactory" withOriginal="true" maxPosAsterisk="3" maxPosQuestion="2" maxFractionAsterisk="0.33"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
</types>
 <fields>
    <field name="url"   type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
    <field name="content"  type="text_general_rev" indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
    <field name="media"  type="string" indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
    <field name="country"  type="string" indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
    <field name="date"  type="string" indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
 </fields>

<defaultSearchField>content</defaultSearchField>
<uniqueKey>url</uniqueKey>

</schema>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it. I increased stack size inside solandra.in.env file. So I have set -Xss512k parameter if someone get same problem.